# Prove a complex integral function is holomorph and computing the derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, derivatives

I need help proving the following statement:

Prove $g(z)$ = $\int_{|w-3i|=5} \frac{|w|^2}{(w-z)^4} $ is holomorph over the compliment of the circle {$w||w-3i|=5$} and computing the derivative.

Here is what I have done so far:

We got that since $\frac{|w|^2}{(w-z)^4} $ is continuous over the compliment of the circle {$w||w-3i|=5$}  and since  the curve  {$w||w-3i|=5$} belong to the analyticity domain of the compliment of  the circle {$w||w-3i|=5$} then $\int_{|w-3i|=5} \frac{|w|^2}{(w-z)^4} $ is zero . So by the Morera theorem  $g(z)$ = $\int_{|w-3i|=5} \frac{|w|^2}{(w-z)^4} $ is holomorph over the compliment of the circle {$w||w-3i|=5$} and the derivative of $g(z)$ = $\int_{|w-3i|=5} \frac{|w|^2}{(w-z)^4} $  is $\frac{|w|^2}{(w-z)^4} $

Is this correct? If yes can you help me filling up the gaps please If not can you help me out by sketching out a prove of the statement. Thanks you, I aprecciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but that fourth paragraph is a bit of a jumble of imprecise and incorrect assertions.

Let $\gamma$ be the circle ${|w-3i|=5}, U = \mathbb {C}\setminus \gamma.$ We have

$$g(z) = \int_\gamma \frac{|w|^2}{(w-z)^4}\,dw, z \in U .$$

I see two approaches:

1. Differentiate through the integral sign with respect to $z.$ Do that without paying attention to rigor and you get the formula
   $$g'(z) = \int_\gamma \frac{4|w|^2}{(w-z)^5}\,dw, z \in U.$$

Now you need to justify the above works.

2. Your approach with Morera. Here you first want to show $g$ is continuous on $U.$ That will be a fairly painless exercise in uniform convergence or the dominated convergence theorem. Then, for $\alpha$ a closed contour in $U,$ you need to show $\int_\alpha g(z)\,dz = 0.$ This will work just fine in showing $g\in H(U)$ (you will need to use Fubini), but the disadvantage is you won't have a formula for $g'(z).$